# Oracle OID SSO does not logout of partner applications on VM PCs

Tags: oracle, oid, oracle-application-server

We have Oracle's OID providing Single Sign-On functionality to Oracle's EnterpriseOne software suite.  Everything was working fine and dandy until we provided some developers access to VM PCs (instead of a regular laptop/desktop).

This is bizarre, but the VM PCs will not logout of the parnter application.  It goes through the motion of saying we are logging out of the partner applications, but after the screen with the check boxes goes away we get sent right back into the application (ie not logged out, sessions still alive, etc...).

Has anyone see behavior like this from VMs before?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a similar behavior with Oracle's UCM product.  The Oracle ADF code actually logs out to the login page.  So if your SSO application is still passing the credentials and the user lands on a URI something like /login?action=logout they will loop right back into the application.  I was able to get around this by intercepting the logout URI and redirecting it to a separate page with out Network Load Balancer.  If you are using a proxy you may be able to use mod_rewrite to do the same.

Comment: Very interesting, so you're normal PCs would logout successfully and just VMs remained in?  I thought the SSO application would need to authenticate back with OID (and determine if they are currently logged in or not) before dropping them back into the application.

Comment: No. Without knowing the actual method in detail how your sso flow goes I can't precisely correlate my issue with yours.  However I would get a tool like fiddler, or HTTPWatch and drill down at the header level to see if there is any difference with how the credentials are flowing in both cases.  Hope that helps.